# Is it good practice to encapsulate mutators in a class inside a JS Module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

We're being as functional as possible with our new product using JavaScript.  I have an Authentication module that has a `tokenPromise` which is updated whenever the user logs in or the token is refreshed.  Seems we have to allow mutation.

Instead of putting `tokenPromise` at the module level, I've created a class that only contains high-level functions that limit how the state can be mutated.  Other helper functions which are pure (or at least don't need to mutate state) are outside the class.  This seems to help a lot in reasoning about when the member might change - it is colocated with all operations that might change it.

I haven't found other examples of such a pattern - is this considered good practice, or is there another way we should be looking at?  Here's the class which contains the mutable data, which is exported from Authentication.ts.

```
export default class Authentication {
  public static async getAuthToken(): Promise<string> {
    if (!this.tokenPromise || await hasExpired(this.tokenPromise)) {
      // Either we've never fetched, or memory was cleared, or expired
      this.tokenPromise = getUpdatedTokenPromise();
    }

    return (await this.tokenPromise).idToken;
  }

  public static async logOut(): Promise<void> {
    this.tokenPromise = null;
    await LocalStorage.clearAuthCredentials();

    // Just restart to log out for now
    RNRestart.Restart();
  }

  private static tokenPromise: Promise<IAuthToken> | null;
}

// After, at the module level, we define all helper functions that don't need to mutate this module's state - getUpdatedAuthToken(), etc.
```

A possible principle seems to be: *keep objects with mutable state as compact as possible, exposing only high-level compact methods to mutate state (e.g. logOut and refreshAuthToken, not get/set authToken)*.

Comment: Why dont you export an object? Looks like you dont need inheritance and object construction...

Comment: @Jonasw something like this?  Seems more efficient as you note, without prototype etc. - the 'static class' pattern just makes more sense from my C# background.  

```
export const Authentication = {
  readonly getAuthToken: async (): Promise<string> => {
```

Comment: _We're being as functional as possible_ Where? This is OO.

Comment: @ftor how would you do it? totally open to alternative implementations leveraging JS and as functional as possible. The functional part comes in creating as many non-mutating, not-using-external-state functions as possible. Again, the team is coming from several years of all C# and learning new best practices.

Answer (score 1):

> I've created a class that only contains high-level functions that limit how the state can be mutated. This seems to help a lot in reasoning about when the member might change - it is colocated with all operations that might change it.

Yes, this is a standard best practice in OOP - the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) by [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) of state changes into the object. No other code outside the object (the class) may mutate it.

> Other helper functions which are pure (or at least don't need to mutate state) are outside the class.

I wouldn't go that far. You should put helper functions (methods?) that belong to instances on the class as well, or at least in its direct vicinity - putting them in the same module might be good enough though. Especially when they access "private" parts of the objects. To just distinguish pure from impure functions, you might also use conventions such as `get` prefixes for pure methods.

An alternative to that is providing a separate immutable interface for your class that contains only the pure methods. You could have this as a second `class` declaration, and use one method to convert between the representations.

> exposing only high-level compact methods to mutate state

I think that's not completely true. You are also implicitly exposing some way to *access* the state (which the pure helper functions would then use), right? You might as well make those explicit.

When dealing with mutable state, the order of writes and reads does not only matter for the internal view (which parts change when) but also on the external (when does the whole object state change). Some convention, like "properties (and getters) are pure, methods might be impure" will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  Will look at a convention like the last one you mentioned.  Separating pure from impure class helper functions is something we're still experimenting with - I'm finding it valuable to have a narrow section of code where "stuff is mutated."